# SilverStripe 3 Left Join Missing argument

Tags: sql, left-join, silverstripe

I have a data object related to some other data objects and I am trying to build a reporting page for them.

So far I've got the code below in my page controller to display a form where I will begin to select filtering options for the report.

However I am getting this error due to the left join:

> [Warning] Missing argument 2 for SQLQuery::addLeftJoin()

It would seem that the raw2sql is outputting this when I've debugged:

> \'AgeRangeData\', \'CallEvent.AgeRangeData ID=AgeRangeData.ID)\'

I'm assuming that the backslashes is what is causing the error

```
public function ReportingFilter(){

    $DataObjectsList = $this->dbObject('DataObjects')->enumValues();

    $fields = new FieldList(
        new DropdownField('DataObjects', 'Data Objects', $DataObjectsList)
    );

    $actions = new FieldList(
        new FormAction("FilterObjects", "Filter")
    );

    return new Form($this, "ReportingFilter", $fields, $actions);
}

public function FilterObjects($data, $form){

    $data = $_REQUEST;
    $query = new SQLQuery();

    $object = $data['DataObjects'];
    $leftJoin = Convert::raw2sql("'" . $object . "', 'CallEvent." . $object . " ID={$object}.ID)'");

    $query->selectField("CallEvent.ID", "ID");
    $query->setFrom('`CallEvent`');
    $query->setOrderBy('CallEvent.Created DESC');
    $query->addLeftJoin($leftJoin);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Don't have time to test these and add them as an answer but as for some tips: Convert::raw2sql should be used to convert a value (or an array)  not a full query statement. See http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/security/secure_coding/ . The Warning comes from  your usage of addLeftJoin and is quite explicit when it says missing argument two: 
$query->addLeftJoin($leftJoin); should be more or less ->addLeftJoin($tablename, $joinstatement)

Comment: my suggestion is to make the left join work with hardcoded values before trying to add the form bits dynamic

Answer (score 3):

[`SQLQuery::addLeftJoin()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SQLQuery.html#_addLeftJoin) takes two arguments. The first is the table to join on and the second is the "on" clause.

You want:

```
$query = new SQLQuery();
$query->addLeftJoin($object, '"CallEvent"."ID" = "' . $object . '"ID"');
```

You'd need to escape `$object` appropriately, of course.

---

NB: Your code looks a little fragile as you're not ensuring that you `$object` actually has a DB table. I recommend you use `ClassInfo::baseDataClass($object)`. This will have the added benefit that it will also sanitise your class name and ensure it's a real class.